How should I respond to a former student from my old institution asking for a reference?
I moved universities about a year ago. In my old institution I had a large number of students, so I did not know most of them personally or remember how they performed.
Sometimes I get emails from former students asking me for reference letters. I find it difficult to know how to respond; usually I will recognise the name, and hence I can say that they did attend the university and did study the relevant programme. But I can't say anything about how well they did, and in most cases I don't remember anything about eg whether they were punctual, or enthusiastic, or engaged, etc.
Usually I point this out and say that I can do a bare-bones letter if they like, but that they would be better asking one of my former colleagues.
How should I respond to these requests?

Be honest with them that you didn't have sufficient interaction with them to be able to write a sufficiently positive letter to help them and that any letter would honestly just be generic. Recommend that they get letters from people who knew them and their work well enough to write an honest and sincerely positive letter.
Anything you could honestly write on their behalf wouldn't help them much. Saying "they did well in my class" is a give-away.
But, the note to them to choose a better source is the most important part. They may not all be aware of how letters are used. (Note: US perspective)

They may be asking you because you are well-known (I have no idea if you are) In that case point out to them that a strong recommendation from somebody unknown is likely to carry more weight than a generic letter from you.

There are plenty of circumstances where a fairly generic letter saying “Firstname Lastname was in the top 20% of my abstract algebra students” is still valuable to the student.  Most obviously: if an employer or graduate-studies institution has a hard requirement of n letters (not uncommon with n=3) and the student has < n instructors that really know them well (not uncommon with n =3, even for good students).

Given that reference letters are often a requirement, even a generic letter is probably enough for some students. I would let the student decide if they want the generic letter, if they're not able to find any other references. (And presumably, they're contacting you because they couldn't.)

Honesty is the best policy. I'm an industry adjunct who works across interdisciplinary boundaries. My memory is good for events and details, but bad on names. So I'm often lost when someone approaches me for a reference.
I tell them I want to help, but given my role don't retain good records and am regretfully not good with names. I ask them to send me a copy of their grade transcript, copies of papers they submitted in my course, and remind me of momentous interactions. Generally, they either ask someone else (probably when they realize that if they got a B, can't find their paper, and did nothing momentous in class they're not going to get a quality reference from me). Or they do remind me of something that makes it all flood back. I make a point of then writing warmly back to make it clear it triggered real memories, and when I write the letter if they were good students I can refer to something prompted by rereading their writing.
I did have one student exaggerate their brilliance in their "reminder". As I said, I actually remember details (just not names) well, so I knew they were exaggerating, and regretfully declined since I "couldn't really remember that". And I did have someone try to fake a higher grade in the grade transcript (something prompted me to check!), which was really dumb. So checking is good if it doesn't feel right.

I have been in identical shoes in the last couple of years. I worked in a university for over seven years. During my experience, I surely met a good number of students, and a few of them are easy to remember for life, mainly because they were serious about their studies, were punctual and discussed quite a bit of research with me. There are this other bunch who used to come to the lectures but were not so easy to remember. Some of them keep emailing me now about the reference letters. No matter how I try to convince them (either by being honest by saying that I could only write a generic letter as others point out in their answers or by plainly saying "No", they still persist). One thing to remember is that they often need three letters of reference, so they keep pushing for a letter from us. One "rude" thing is to just ignore such an email, but then it is just "rude" and "unprofessional". So I tell them very clearly that I will just write a generic one that the universities might never count and if they are okay with it, I just say ok. Surprisingly, most of them are okay with that.

“Surprisingly, most of them are okay with that.” — This seems understandable enough. Some universities/employers do have a hard formal requirement of three letters (often enforced by an automatic system), and many decent students only genuinely get to know one or two instructors. So they need one or two more letters — however generic — to fulfil the formal requirement, and get their application (including their other non-generic letters) considered by a human.

Ah, I see. I didn't know about the automatic system. I was under the impression that universities do read all three letters. @PLL

I tend to give such students a brief description of what I'd be able to write, and ask them if that's good enough for their purposes.
Oddly enough, this happened exactly this way about two weeks ago.  I got a very last-minute request from a student who wasn't a great exam taker in one of my classes, and got a B, but did very well in a different team-based course. I told the requester the best statement I could make about his classroom skills was a confidence that the student could pass a graduate curriculum, that I could go stronger in other areas, and I would be unable to use the phrase "without reservation".
I fully expected the student to say "no thanks", but he said "that will be great, thanks".  I submitted the recommendation, and was notified by the student three days later that they were accepted.
Yeah, this may have been a very special case.
It was clearly a late application, and it's conceivable that everything was all arranged for this student, and the application was simply a formality for this student, and all else was well in hand.  The point is that there's no way I could know this stuff.  I didn't particularly want to know this stuff --- but the student is most certainly aware of their own situation.  So, where I landed is to tell the student what the best I could write about them was, and let the student make the choice.

The best thing to do is to tell the student that you are not a good referee for them because of the (entirely legitimate) reasons you give, and as a result you can only provide a generic reference.
You should advise them it would be wiser for them to ask some else, but I would personally agree to proceed if they insist knowing that some students might be very much hard pressed to ask someone else.  The good students will recognize your situation.

Excellent replies here but a tiny warning: If you you do write a reference for someone you really can't remember and they they get the position but turn out to be, shall we say not quite up to scratch, then you have the problem of your name being associated with their failure. Not a happy position for either of you to be in. Just be honest with your ex-students and wish them luck with their endeavours.
